# Excel or open office calc how to remove last white space?

Tags: microsoft-excel, openoffice-calc

Excel or open office calc how to remove last white space?

Comment: More detail please. Do you want a formula to remove the last white space character from a given cell/string? Do you mean *any* white space or just a normal space character? Is the space always trailing, or somewhere in the string body?

Comment: Who in their right mind would upvote this "question"?

Comment: I came here searching for "remove trailing white space openoffice calc" - The Trim function that kikbira suggested worked a charm. - So I think the question is a good one - how ever badly phrased.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Trim()](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/trim.php) function